# Egit Eclipse insufficient data written)

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Can't connect to repository: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git (An internal Exception occurred during push: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git: insufficient data written).
I'm using eclipse.Help to solve this problem

Comment: I face the same problem. I manage to push one of the project but can't push it for another one.

Comment: Hi, i had similar problem too...Thing is when you add some new file to your values folder, (like new picture for layout, or something like that), if they are too big, Eclipse have problem to push them to remote repositiries, becouse of size. In my case that was problem, and i had to resize those files, to smaler, and eventualy i managed to push. I say again this was in my case, you might have somethig different, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Push can be a issue if our latest working set have differnet lagging timesStamp,

you can follow the below steps
1) commit your code locally
2) pull the code from remote master
3) synch your workspace with local repository
4) commit and push your code again.

if still now working then
Search all .git files from your local repository and push again. it will work for sure.